# Vi - Jump to char sequence in line

Tags: vim, navigation, vi, ex

Is there a command to quickly jump to a typed char sequence in the current line in Vi? Kinda type-and-seach in a file explorer. 
I'm aware, that I can jump to the next specified char with `fa` (where 'a' is the wanted character here) or reverse with a capital `F`. But often a single character does not help. I know also, that I can search with `/` or `?` and a regular expression. But that's to much and to slow for this use case. My alternative is then to use the 'find char' command with a number or do the same with `b`... 
To break it down, I'm searching for something like `fabc`, where `fa` jumps to the next 'a'. When hitting the 'b' it goes to the next char sequence 'ab' (could be the same position) and so further with 'c'. 
Maybe this is a bit special. But as Bram Moolenaar said: "While you are editing, keep an eye out for actions you repeat and/or spend quite a bit of time on." [[1]](http://www.moolenaar.net/habits.html)

Comment: there are a lot of plugins:
https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion f.e. (for that use case a bit slow) i am sure you will find some which allow `f` with two characters instead of just one. A quick tip i can give you is that you can repeat motions with `;` so you can use `fa;;;` to jump to the 4th `a` in the line. And  you can even revert it `,` and use a count `fa3;` is the same as `fa;;;`

Comment: easymotion +1 .

Comment: `/foo<CR>` is too much and too slow?

Comment: @romainl does not feel so great. Can't explain it...

Comment: easymotion seems to be awesome. Thanks for this great hint!

Comment: Short of using something like easymotion you do still have an option if your perception of searching with "/" is too slow: using the incremental search function (`set incsearch`).  This causes the cursor to jump visually to the next match while you type rather than waiting for you to press return.  I say visually because the cursor doesn't actually move until you press return.  The point is that you can type just enough to know you'll land where you want before you press enter to actually move.

Comment: @RandyMorris also a good hint. Thank you!

Comment: weird / doesn't feel right....not sure what youd expect   need some char to get into some kind of search, the chars to look for, and something to say you've entered all the chars

Comment: I completly understand it. Pressing enter is somewhat far away, it is a lot easier to just use a plugin which allows an `f` movement to 2 chars (easy motion is not a good example, it needs a lot more key presses than `/`). 
But `/` can be used for a lot more usecases. so it is probably worth to get used to it.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo so far I was still using a German keyboard layout. `/` need more effort. But I just order an English keyboard for my computer. Should help in general.